# What is the process for handling an employee who is retaliating against me for reporting him for drinking on the job?

Tags: professionalism

I recently reported an employee for drinking on the job. I had spoken to him personally first to express my concerns, and he both admitted and told me it wouldn't happen again.

After a few more instances he was required to take daily breathalyzer tests before work. This past week he heard about me making a comment at a meeting he wasn't present for. This comment wasn't about him yet he texted me 2x after midnight to say I was a bully prick. I didn't read these until the following morning.

Not knowing who had sent them, I called the number, confronted him about talking to me face to face. He proceeded to leave 2 more voice messages ranting about me being a bully prick and that he wasn't afraid of me. At no time had I ever threatened him.

I spoke with my boss, and he made a call to this employee. While I wasn't present, I could hear some of the conversation. Part of which I believe he was making false accusations about me. I'm awaiting a follow up meeting with my boss. I feel that this employee is trying to get back at me for turning him in.

Could this be considered retaliation for me reporting him? What is the process for handling an employee who is retaliating against me for reporting him?

Comment: Do you both report to the same manager?  Or is one of you the manager of the other?  Where you sit on the org chart relative to each other will change the right response.

Comment: Retaliation? In all likelihood, yes. He may be drunk at those moments. Whatever you do *keep all evidence*.

Comment: We are both technically same level.I have 2.5 yrs over him and we both report to the same boss.

Comment: Do you guys do something where his drinking is putting you at risk?

Comment: @blankip, yes, that is an important question here. If not, then one has to wonder what the OP could possibly gain from this. Even in best-case, fully-justified scenarios whistleblowers suffer consequences. One of them is retaliation. If the OP somehow manages to protect himself from the retaliation, he will have sown seeds of  distrust into the other co-workers. They're left to wonder if their vice is the next target for his judgement and action.

Comment: Yes,dangerous gases and chemical.

Answer (score 6):

1. Could this be considered retaliation for me reporting him?

Whether it could be considered retaliation is not what's important. The employee's behavior is inappropriate for the workplace, and that's all there is to it.

2. What is the process for handling an employee who is retaliating against me for reporting him?

You should really ask your own HR instead of us.

Comment: In many companies, "retaliation" is specifically frowned upon, so the same behaviour would be considered worse if it is "retaliation". Obviously, it is inappropriate even if it is not retaliation.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'd leave it up to HR to make the determination whether the employee's behavior amounts to retaliation. Needless to say, being caught retaliating against someone for having reported one's own inappropriate behavior - that's usually a resume generating event.

Comment: I've had the weekend to think this out.I will hear out my manager as to what was said about me but I'm going to ask for HR help with this.Just wanted some clarification because most of what I've read was employer retaliation against an employee.My case is employee against employee.